# How do I Copy Properties From one HttpWebRequest to Another?

Tags: c#, reflection, properties, httpwebrequest

I am currently writing a Lib to make use of a HttpWebRequest class and properties. After calling certain methods I will need my HttpWebRequest attribute of the class to be reconstructed, but not from scratch.

This is what I want to accomplish:

1. Backup the properties from the existing HttpWebRequest

   System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] properties = m_HttpWebRequest.GetType ().GetProperties ();
2. Re-instantiate the attribute, creating a new WebRequest

   m_HttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
3. Add the copied properties to the new instance. Which I am unable to do yet.

Any ideas of how to implement the third step?
Currently I can get the name of each Property by using:

```
properties[index].Name
```

But I can't reference the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should roughly get you there:

```
foreach(var prop in m_HttpWebRequest.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    if(!(prop.CanWrite && prop.CanRead))
        continue;

    var val = prop.GetValue(m_HttpWebRequest, BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, null, null);
    if (val == null)
        continue;

    prop.SetValue(m_HttpWebRequest2, val, BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, null, null);
}
```

Comment: This looks like what i wanted to,let me try it now.
I will let you know soon if it worked.
Thanks !

Comment: The code is untested and written from memory, but I've written it a few dozen times so I'm fairly confident it will work as it is.

Comment: "Property set method not found."
Forth Property Raised this error. Name is : "HaveResponse"

Comment: I'll adjust my answer. I didn't take into consideration read only properties.

Comment: I just added : If (prop.CanWrite && prop.CanRead) then, setValue.

I went far this time,but another exception was raised : "TargetInvocationException Was Unhandled"

Comment: InnerException {"The Content-Length value must be greater than or equal to zero.\r\nParameter name: value"}System.Exception {System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException}

Comment: You'll need to figure out what value `Content-Length` has in `m_HttpWebRequest`. I'd guess the get is returning `null` which is causing the exception. I'll adjust my code to ignore null properties but doing so could have undesirable results.

Comment: Sorry to bothering you,but, what are the possibles `undesirable results`?

Comment: Your basically skipping properties doing this. It shouldn't make a difference if the default value for the property is null anyway.

Comment: i Just checked, there is no `property with null value`. 
Damn, i will try to figure it out myself again. Thanks for all the help Mr @M.Babcock

Comment: Properties that are raising exception just FYI : Connection,Headers and ContentLength.

Comment: A simple (and dirty) solution would be to put a `try...catch` in the loop and just ignore the properties that throw exceptions. Then just implement the code manually to copy over the properties that are giving you trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(m_HttpWebRequest, null);
```

Your case:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in m_HttpWebRequest.GetType().GetProperties())
{
     if (propertyInfo.GetValue(m_HttpWebRequest, null) != null) propertyInfo.SetValue(m_HttpWebRequest2,propertyInfo.GetValue(m_HttpWebRequest, null), null);
}
```

Read more about it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty.aspx

Comment: 'properties[0].GetValue(null,null)' threw an exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetException' object {System.Reflection.TargetException}

Comment: Sorry about that, I gave you the most generic description I could think of at that moment. I customized it into your specific case, but by now @M.Babcock has a better answer :)